# Atomically swap contents of two files on Linux

Tags: linux, libc

I have two files, `A` and `B`, each with its own content.

I would like to swap these two files, so `A` would become `B`, and `B` would become `A`. But I would like to do with a guaranty that no other process will find these two files in an inconsistent state, nor any process will find any of those files missing, even for a short while. So, as a side operation, I would also like to have a guaranty that if anything would go wrong during the operation, nothing will be changed (kind of like a transaction I guess).

On OS X there is a `exchangedata()` function, so I guess I'm looking for a Linux equivalent of it, or at least an equivalent method for doing atomic file swap.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - the answer to the question you've posted doesn't meet my criteria at all, so I guess it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I thought the answers there would suit you, but I guess you don't want to leave a temporary file around if something goes wrong?

Comment: Yes, as well as I would like to have a guaranty that I won't remove the original file. If first move will succeed, I will effectively remove the file. Then, if second move will fail, I will have to rollback. If rollback also fails, I will be in trouble for destroying the systems of the customers ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the (fairly recent) [linux syscall `renameat2`](http://lwn.net/Articles/569134/)

Here is the definition :

```
int renameat2(int olddir, const char *oldname, 
      int newdir, const char *newname, unsigned int flags);
```

You can find its source code on [the kernel's Git repo](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/namei.c?id=7bb91e06730140a693611e51a4a9636152448bd3#n4474) if needed.

It's basically the same as `renameat`, but if you pass the flag RENAME_EXCHANGE it will swap the two files instead of renaming one into the other.

The operation is atomic.

Comment: The kernel documentation document that describes this syscall can be found [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html).

Comment: By the way, `RENAME_EXCHANGE` was added to the Linux kernel in v3.15 according to [SourceDigger](https://sourcedigger.io/linux?q=RENAME_EXCHANGE)

Answer (score 2):

I depends on what you mean by "inconsistent state".  If it is acceptable for there to be a period of time during which the two files are identical, then you can simply do:

```
ln A C
ln B D
ln -f D A  
# now, A and B have the same content
ln -f C B
```

It also depends on the behavior you want for processes that already have the file opened.  Remember that paths are *not* files, but merely links to a file, so if process 1 opens a file via the path 'A', and then you swap the names A and B, process 1 will still have the file opened that was referred to by the name A.

Comment: Explanations for the downvotes are welcome. This solves the question as asked, with the minor caveat of the ambiguity in the question which is addressed.

Comment: I did some experiments, and it seems that using the `-f` flag fails to meet with the 'atomicity' constraint, as the `ln` tool uses `unlink` to remove the destination path before creating a link with `link` function. So `ln -f` is not really atomic, there is a (very brief, but still) time window when the file doesn't exist. Having this in mind, simply swapping by renaming using a temporary file name seems to do the same thing similarly.